# Does speaker calibration software reduce the life-span of the speakers?

Tags: monitors, calibration

I'm wondering if using speaker calibration software could be exhausting the speakers by gaining up the frequencies outside of the speaker's natural frequency range, or if there is anything to be careful about.  Is calibration going to make much difference when producing music (I'm sure people have had success without it), and if it's so important then why don't we see calibration functions on consumer hi-fi or TV's?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see it on consumer units because consumers don't need it enough to pay for it, nor could most of them tell the difference anyway judging by what most people's TV's & HiFi's sound like ;) Give a consumer a graphic EQ & they will just put a 'smile' on it without thinking any further.

This is what I had to strap permanently over a consumer 2.1 system recently to make it sound anything like flat. The bizarre shaping at the bottom is to overcome the ridiculously over-zealous sub, which actually only really pushes mid-low properly & leaves the actual lows out unless shoved hard.

[image]

...which I suppose brings us closer to an answer -
if you pull frequencies rather than push, then you're making the system do "less work" in its over-emphasised areas, rather than more. Having said that, unless you are going to run it at full tilt, it ought to be well within tolerance to run with that curve applied, forever. I have no worries for the low-budget consumer system I just EQ'd to death, it just never runs loud enough to become a worry, though that amount of extra 'shove' at the bottom end would heat the voice-coils if it was run at excessive levels.
This wasn't a true calibration, btw, just by ear - sufficient that I knew it sounded OK & its owner couldn't actually tell the difference until I A/B'd it for them, then they realised how the original managed to be fizzy, boxy & boomy... all at the same time ;)

A better system would usually need a lot less rough handling than that.